# how to convert string to date and keep the format correct

Tags: java, string, datetime, date, simpledateformat

I am reading in a `String` from a text file which contains a date in the form of `yyMMdd` I then want to convert it to type `date` but when I do that it loses its format. here is an exmaple of what I have tried

```
String strDate = matcher.group(10); // strDate would contain 111107

SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
Date date = formatter1.parse(strDate); // after parsing it, the format changes to Thu Nov 03 00:00:00 EDT 2011
```

But if I take `date` and put it back into a string like so `String tDate = formatter1.format(date);` the string then contains the date in the format Id like to see `111107`.

Is there a way I can do this? maybe if I could some how call the `format` function to return a `date` object instead of `String`, thanks.

**Edit**
I read a list of dates in from a file and load them into a map I then compare those dates to the current date which is also in the `yyMMdd` format and then if the date from the map is more then a week earlier than the current date I prompt the user for input and then write the date and other related info to a file, in the `yyMMdd` format. The reason I use a map is each line of the text file contains some information and a unique name, and I compared the date for that specific line of data so I do a `map.get(aName)`

here is the code, hope it helps

```
dbConnect();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "select * from OBJECT_BAC_EV where instance = 12";//VALUE <> 'Normal'";
            rslt = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
            String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
            Date curDate = (Date)formatter.parse(dateNow);
            currentDate.setTime(curDate);
            currentDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
            dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
            curDate = (Date)formatter.parse(dateNow);

            Calendar cDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
            String strDate = f.format(cDate.getTime());

            while(rslt.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rslt.getRow());

                String aValue = rslt.getString("VALUE");
                String aName = rslt.getString("NAME");
                String aObjRef = rslt.getString("ObjRef");


                if(aNoteMap.containsKey(aName))
                {

                    String n = aNoteMap.get(aName);
                    if(aDateMap.get(aName).before(curDate))
                    {
                        int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to use last weeks note? " + n, "Hey", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                        if( answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                        {
                            output.write(aName + "    "  + aObjRef + "    "  + aValue + "    "  + aDateMap.get(aName) + "    "
                                     + n  + (System.getProperty("line.separator")));
                        }
                        else if( answer == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                        {
                            String newNote = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new note");
                            output.write(aName + "    "  + aObjRef + "    "  + aValue + "    "  + aDateMap.get(aName) + "    "
                                     + newNote  + (System.getProperty("line.separator")));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        output.write(aName + "    "  + aObjRef + "    "  + aValue + "    "  + aDateMap.get(aName) + "    "
                                 + n  + (System.getProperty("line.separator")));
                }
                else
                    output.write(aName + "    "  + aObjRef + "    "  + aValue + "    "  + strDate + "    "
                            + ""  + (System.getProperty("line.separator")));
            }
            System.out.println("its closing output..");
            output.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Date class has no "internal" format, it only represents date elements. To output it using a specific format, you need to do the way you did: `String tDate = formatter1.format(date);`

The reason why you think it has the "wrong format" is probably because when you try to output it, it does a `toString()` by default, which doesn't format it the way you want.

If you give us more details about how you want to use that date (include your code), then we might be able to provide suggestions on how to inject the formatter into it.

Answer (score 2):

`Date` always stores the complete information including time. If you parse the date with a `SimpleDateFormat` that does not contain time info, these fields are set to 0 as in your example.

`Date` does not store any format info itself.

Answer (score 2):

The SimpleDateFormat.format method always returns a String. It represents the 'date' parameter as a String, with the specified format. For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('yyMMdd');
Date date = sdf.parse("110510");
String sDate = sdf.format(date); //"110510"

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy.MM.dd');
String sDate2 = sdf2.format(date); //2011.05.10
```

It's the best thing for formatting a Date Object.

Answer (score 1):

Written using [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), it would like this :

```
String str = "110107";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendYearOfCentury(2, 2)
  .appendMonthOfYear(2)
  .appendDayOfWeek(2)
  .toFormatter();

DateTime dateFromDB = formatter.parseDateTime(str);//create DateTime instance
System.out.println("Date:" + formatter.print(dateFromDB));//toString in required format
```

And it has many other benefits, apparently it will replace the existing Java date libs, which have always been rather painful, in upcoming java releases.

One of the benefits is

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
Integer compared = now.minusWeeks(1).compareTo(dateFromDB);
```

And compareTo does the [expected](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#compareTo%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
class MyDate extends java.util.Date {
  static final SimpleDateFormat yymmddFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");

  public MyDate (String s) throws ParseException {
    super(yymmddFormat.parse(s).getTime());
  }

  public String toString () {
    return yymmddFormat.format(this);
  }
}
```

Use this class everywhere you currently use a Date object. This should make all your dates look as you want them.